# Datagrid column headers and values binding

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I'm having a problem with binding columns headers and values to data grid in MVVM PRISM.

I'm having class SearchResult that has two properties :

- ColumnNames ---> those will apply to headers
- ColumnValues ---> those will apply to specific headers as their values.

  public class SearchResult
  {
      public List ColumnNames;

  ```
  public List<object> ColumnValues;

  public string ColumnName { get; set; }
  public object ColumnValue { get; set; }

  public SearchResult()
  {
      this.ColumnNames = new List<string>();
      this.ColumnValues = new List<object>();
  }

  public void AddColumnAttributes(string columnName, object columnValue)
  {
      this.ColumnNames.Add(columnName);
      this.ColumnValues.Add(columnValue);
      this.ColumnName = columnName;
      this.ColumnValue = columnValue;
  }
  ```

  }

those properties are lists that are populated dynamically through C# code.

And I need to bind them to columns headers and columns values in XAML.

I've already created ObservableCollection Result which is the source of my gridview, but still is doesn't bind headers and values.

```
public ObservableCollection<SearchResult> Result
    {
        get { return this.searchResult; }
        set 
        { 
            this.searchResult = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("SearchResult");
        }
    }
```

And XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResult}" Width="350">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ColumnName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

I'll appreciate any help with this!!!

Comment: Please provide the relevant non-working code.

Comment: Can you edit your original question and add the code content there rather than in comments please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thick your code should be like this..

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResult, ElementName=PageTitle}" Width="350">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ColumnNames/ColumnName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"></TextBlock>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```